# Error rate during training and test phase Scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was wondering if there is a method to estimate the error during the training and testing phases. Since the accuracy of both training and testing could be estiamted by using this:

```
classifier.score(X_train,y_train)
classifier.score(X_test,y_test)
```

Is there any equivalence for error rate?

Or a function for this purpose can be implemented?

Comment: How is error different from (1 - score) for your situation? We need more information to assess this.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you mean by error rate

Comment: It is already solved using 1-score. Thanks